# jQuery: How do I sent a complex form to a div using post()?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post

I have a complex form including round about 40 input fields and checkboxes.

e.g.

```
<form action="send.php" id="myForm" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  ...
  <input type="text" name="age">

  <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckgroup1[]">
  <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckgroup1[]">
  <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckgroup1[]">

  <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckgroup2[]">
  ...
  <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox_1">
</form>

<div id="result">Here is your result</div>
```

So, I have different form fields. Is there any way to get all of these to be sent to the "send.php" in the "result"-div (with jQuery ajax/post)?
Of course they should keep their names :-)

Thanks a lot
best regards
Jan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `serialize` on the jQuery form object (also don't forget to call `e.preventDefault()` to stop the form submitting):

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
    // Stop form submitting normally
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr("action"),
        type: $form.attr("method"),
        data: $form.serialize()
    }).done(function(data){
        $("#result").html(data);           // As suggested by HarryFink
    });
});
```

This example also gets the url and other settings from the form attributes.

Serialize will convert all inputs (including hidden inputs) into name/value pairs. This looks the same to the server as if the page was submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can serialize your from and then send it with ajax like this:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        url: $(this).attr('action')
    });
});
```

Comment: And append something like this: `.done(function(data) {$('#result').html(data);})` to the $.ajax call